# Error (Xcode): could not compile `super_native_extensions` (lib) due to 58 previous errors

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to run a Flutter program on my M1 Macbook Pro and am using Xcode 15.0.1. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro in debug mode...

Xcode build done. 36.7s

Failed to build iOS app Error

(Xcode): could not compile super_native_extensions (lib) due to 58 previous errors 

/Users/yanivsagy/code/instaboard/instaboard/ios/Pods/SEVERE:0:0` 

Could not build the application for the simulator. 

Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.
```

Does anybody have an idea about how to resolve this?

Comment: Please include full output. These previous 58 errors are crucial

Comment: It appears that updating my Rust version resolved the issue. Apologies for coming back to this so late, but thank you for your help.

Comment: "It appears that updating my Rust version resolved the issue" , can you tell us more ?